# Passing a command line argument to a py.test fixture as a parameter

Tags: python, pytest

Admittedly it is not the best way to do it to start with and more importantly the fixture parameters are resolved i.e. Options.get_option() is called before everything else. 
Recommendations and suggestions would be appreciated.

From config.py

```
class Options(object):
    option = None

    @classmethod
    def get_option(cls):
        return cls.option
```

From conftest.py

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def session_setup():
    Options.option = pytest.config.getoption('--remote')

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--remote", action="store_true", default=False, help="Runs tests on a remote service.")




@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function', params=Options.get_option())
def setup(request):
    if request.param is None:
        raise Exception("option is none")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use custom `Options` class but directly ask for option from config.

`pytest_generate_tests` may be used for parametrizing fixture-like argument for tests.

conftest.py

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--pg_tag", action="append", default=[],
                     help=("Postgres server versions. "
                           "May be used several times. "
                           "Available values: 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, all"))

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'pg_tag' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        tags = set(metafunc.config.option.pg_tag)
        if not tags:
            tags = ['9.5']
        elif 'all' in tags:
            tags = ['9.3', '9.4', '9.5']
        else:
            tags = list(tags)
        metafunc.parametrize("pg_tag", tags, scope='session')

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def pg_server(pg_tag):
    # pg_tag is parametrized parameter
    # the fixture is called 1-3 times depending on --pg_tag cmdline
```

**Edit**: Replaced old example with `metafunc.parametrize` usage.

Comment: As much as I would like to avoid that to automatically generate test parameters and run all tests per each parameter I need to use the class.

Comment: Now I understand your needs.

See rewritten example, it uses `pytest_generate_tests` and `metafunc.parametrize` for adding paramtrized parameters

Comment: This example should be in the docs. I have used all the pieces, but had not thought about this combination. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a pytest contributor but if you would to make a Pull Request to documentation -- you are welcome, sure.

Answer (score 4):

There is an example in the latest docs on how to do this.  It's a little buried and honestly I glazed over it the first time reading through the documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example.

> ### Basic pytest_generate_tests example
>
> Sometimes you may want to implement your own parametrization scheme or
>   implement some dynamism for determining the parameters or scope of a
>   fixture. For this, you can use the pytest_generate_tests hook which is
>   called when collecting a test function. Through the passed in metafunc
>   object you can inspect the requesting test context and, most
>   importantly, you can call metafunc.parametrize() to cause
>   parametrization.
>
> For example, let’s say we want to run a test taking string inputs
>   which we want to set via a new pytest command line option. Let’s first
>   write a simple test accepting a stringinput fixture function argument:
>
> ```
> # content of test_strings.py
>
> def test_valid_string(stringinput):
>     assert stringinput.isalpha()
> ```
>
> Now we add a conftest.py file containing the addition of a command
>   line option and the parametrization of our test function:
>
> ```
> # content of conftest.py
>
> def pytest_addoption(parser):
>     parser.addoption("--stringinput", action="append", default=[],
>         help="list of stringinputs to pass to test functions")
>
> def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
>     if 'stringinput' in metafunc.fixturenames:
>         metafunc.parametrize("stringinput",
>                              metafunc.config.getoption('stringinput'))
> ```
>
> If we now pass two stringinput values, our test will run twice:
>
> ```
> $ pytest -q --stringinput="hello" --stringinput="world" test_strings.py`
> ..
> 2 passed in 0.12 seconds
> ```

Comment: Plesae copy here the concerned content. Links can be removed or changed